# Implementation of data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, implementation

i just want to know what is the suitable data structure to implement for:
1. storing the recently visited web addresses on a web browser?
2. the processes to be scheduled on the CPU of a computer?
3. the undo mechanism in a text editor like Notepad?

Comment: 1. list/array 2.queue 3.stack

Answer (score 0):

> 1. storing the recently visited web addresses on a web browser?

If you want to store the `k` last addresses, you can use a queue.

If the queue is smaller than `k` - just add the new address.

If it's of size `k`, delete the last element in the queue (one inserted first, the "oldest" entry), and insert the new one.

Might want to combine it with a set (or a map that maps to the queue's entry) to make sure an entry is not filling multiples values in your queue.

If you don't need to ever delete entries (and the number of "visited" elements is unbounded), you can use a set.

> 2. the processes to be scheduled on the CPU of a computer?

There are many options for that, but some simple ones are using a queue, or a priority queue (heap).

> 3. the undo mechanism in a text editor like Notepad?

A stack. Each "do" is a push, and to "Undo", you pop the last element and revert its action.

Comment: Web addresses, plural, so multiple.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for pointing that out, read it as a single address. Fixed.